# Stringstream - Convert an object to a string

Tags: c++, stringstream

I have a complex object that I want to be able to pass into a `std::ostringstream` with the `<<` operator just like a string or int. I want to give the ostringstream the object's unique id (int) and/or name (string). Is there an operator or method I can implement in my class to allow this to work?

Comment: Yes just overload the << operator - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading

Comment: unique id in what context? In an instance of running process you could use it's memory address.

Comment: They are "Student" objects, for a class project. Each Student object has a name, id, address, and phone number, and are built from a txt file.

Comment: @MartinBeckett - overload << for my class, or for `ostringstream`?

Comment: @mouseas - for your class. Each class simply has a function that is called when you ask for '<<' which prints the values. It's just that for int/float/double etc they are built-in

Comment: Well, make an answer, then. What should the return be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define an operator overload in the same namespace as your class:

```
template<typename charT, typename traits>
std::basic_ostream<charT, traits> &
operator<< (std::basic_ostream<charT, traits> &lhs, Your_class const &rhs) {
    return lhs << rhs.id() << ' ' << rhs.name();
}
```

If the output function needs access to private members of your class then you can define it as a friend function:

```
class Your_class {
    int id;
    string name;

    template<typename charT, typename traits>
    friend std::basic_ostream<charT, traits> &
    operator<< (std::basic_ostream<charT, traits> &lhs, Your_class const &rhs) {
        return lhs << rhs.id << ' ' << rhs.name;
    }
};
```

Note that this does not result in a member function, it's just a convenient way to declare and define a friend function at once.

Comment: The `traits` template parameter has a default value, so it can be skipped.